# print digits separately and print number n for n times in front of it

Tags: c++, loops

I wanna have digits of an integer separately and print digit n for n times in front of that digit
Like:

4: 4444
3: 333

I've got this so far but it prints 4: 3: and I dunno how to make it to what I want :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stack>

int countDigitsInInteger(int n)
{
    int count =0;
    while(n>0)
    {
        count++;
        n=n/10;
    }
    return count;
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    int intLength =0;
    int number;
    int digit;      
    string s;    
    cin >>number;
    if (number<0)
        number = -number;    

    intLength = countDigitsInInteger(number);
    stack<int> digitstack;
    while(number>0)
    {                         
        digit = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        digitstack.push(digit);
    }

    while(digitstack.size() > 0)
    {
        cout << digitstack.top() << ":"<< endl ;
        digitstack.pop();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I also know how to write n for n times in a separate program but I dunno how to combine these codes and make one program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

void printNTimes(char c, int n) 
{  
    cout << string(n, c) << endl; 
}

int main() 
{ 
    int n = 6; 
    char c = 'G'; 

    printNTimes(c, n); 

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert your integer to a `std::string` and then loop over the `char`s in that string.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int number = 43; // or read it from std::cin

    std::string snumber = std::to_string(number);

    for(auto ch : snumber) {     // a range-based loop over the chars in snumber
        std::cout << ch << ": "; // print the char

        // loop the number of times that you want to print the char:
        for(int count = ch - '0'; count; --count)
            std::cout << ch;     // print the char
        std::cout << '\n';

        // or:
        //
        // std::cout << std::string(ch - '0', ch) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4: 4444
3: 333
```